# List databricks secret scope and find referred keyvault in azure databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, azure-keyvault

How can we find existing secret scopes in databricks workspace. And which keyvault is referred by specific SecretScope in Azure Databricks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with either:

- [Databricks Secrets REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/secrets) - the [list secret scopes API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/secrets#--list-secret-scopes) will give that information
- [Databricks CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/cli/) - the `databricks secrets list-scopes` command will show your KeyVault URL

Answer (score 9):

This command lists available scopes on databricks:

```
dbutils.secrets.listScopes()
```

Comment: So this was my intent to post this questions, as I was wondering if there's way to do it via Notebook itself. thanks!

Comment: This answer does not include showing the keyvault that is backed by the scope.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a quick idea of which keyvault a secret scope refers to, the number of vaults is relatively small, you have list access through Azure portal and the keys between the vaults differ, you can try the following:

First list the scopes using:

`dbutils.secrets.listScopes()` (Thanks to Matkurek)

And then list the secret names within specific scopes using:

`dbutils.secrets.list("SCOPE_NAME")`

This might help you pin down which vault the scope points to.

It seams that the only alternative is the CLI option described by Alex Ott

Answer (score 0):

You can try this snippet here in Python:

```
import pandas
import json
import requests

# COMMAND ----------

# MAGIC %md ### define variables

# COMMAND ----------

pat           = 'EnterPATHere'           # paste PAT. Get it from settings > user settings
workspaceURL  = 'EnterWorkspaceURLHere'  # paste the workspace url in the format of 'https://adb-1234567.89.azuredatabricks.net' Note, the URL must not end with '/'

# COMMAND ----------

# MAGIC %md ### list secret scopes

# COMMAND ----------

response = requests.get(workspaceURL + '/api/2.0/secrets/scopes/list',\
            headers = {'Authorization' :      'Bearer '+ pat,\
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'})

pandas.json_normalize(json.loads(response.content), record_path = 'scopes')
```

I have happened to have written a [blog post](https://www.tackytech.blog/how-to-manage-azure-key-vault-backed-scopes-in-databricks/) about this where a full Python script is provided to manage secret scopes in Azure Databricks.