# Cannot create secret scope: Azure KeyVault is not available. Terraform

Tags: terraform, azure-databricks, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-provider-databricks

I'm deploying a keyvault and a databricks resource with terraform. The resources are deploy via a Service Principal that will give contributor rights to every thing it deploys.

I also added to myself contributor role for the KeyVault and created a user that is assigned to admin group in Databricks.

I followed the documentation on how to create a secret scope on databricks, it worked with the UI with my account. But I wish to automate this with Terraform, so I added this in my tf file:

```
resource "databricks_secret_scope" "kv_db" {
  name = module.keyvault_gb.name

  keyvault_metadata {
    resource_id = module.keyvault_gb.id
    dns_name    = module.keyvault_gb.uri
  }
}
```

This is the result of my terraform plan

```
  # databricks_secret_scope.kv_db will be created
  + resource "databricks_secret_scope" "kv_db" {
      + backend_type = (known after apply)
      + id           = (known after apply)
      + name         = "xxxxxx"

      + keyvault_metadata {
          + dns_name    = "https://xxxxxx.vault.azure.net/"
          + resource_id = "/subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/*********/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/xxxxxx"
        }
    }
```

And the result of my terraform apply

```
│ Error: cannot create secret scope: Azure KeyVault is not available
│ 
│   with databricks_secret_scope.kv_db,
│   on databricks.tf line 68, in resource "databricks_secret_scope" "kv_db":
│   68: resource "databricks_secret_scope" "kv_db" {
```

I don't understand why it does not work in terraform since I managed to create one with the UI. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/secret-scopes#create-an-azure-key-vault-backed-secret-scope-using-the-ui)

The only difference is the user used, the UI is my own user, and the terraform is a Service Principal that has contributor role on all resources deployed by it. The SP is also admin member on databricks.

I even tried to recreate the keyvault policy to be sure to add the good rights for the SP, but the policy already exists:

```
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" { # Using the deployement Service Principal
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "this" {
  key_vault_id       = module.keyvault_gb.id
  tenant_id          = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id          = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
  secret_permissions = ["Delete", "Get", "List", "Set"]
}
```

> │ Error: A resource with the ID "/subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/xxxxx/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/xxxxxx/objectId/xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx" already exists - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State. Please see the resource documentation for "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" for more information.

Update:
Here are the rights of the role of the SP used to deploy the KeyVault/Databricks and attempting to create the secret scope
[image: SP KeyVault]

Here is the role of my user:
[image]

Update 2: I added more roles to the SP, but still not working.
[image]

Update 3:
Using @Vinay-B code and changing the keyvault name, this is what I get in terraform plan and apply:

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # azurerm_resource_group.example will be created
  + resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + location = "eastus"
      + name     = "demorgvk1"
    }

  # azurerm_key_vault.example will be created
  + resource "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
      + access_policy                 = (known after apply)
      + id                            = (known after apply)
      + location                      = "eastus"
      + name                          = "kv-3-stackoverflow"
      + public_network_access_enabled = true
      + resource_group_name           = "demorgvk1"
      + sku_name                      = "standard"
      + soft_delete_retention_days    = 90
      + tenant_id                     = "***"
      + vault_uri                     = (known after apply)
    }

  # azurerm_key_vault_access_policy.example will be created
  + resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "example" {
      + id                 = (known after apply)
      + key_vault_id       = (known after apply)
      + object_id          = "4ace89c9-93bf-4041-b6e9-bc73c2fcb144"
      + secret_permissions = [
          + "Get",
          + "List",
          + "Set",
          + "Delete",
        ]
      + tenant_id          = "***"
    }

  # azurerm_resource_group.example will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
        id       = "/subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/demorgvk1"
        name     = "demorgvk1"
      ~ tags     = {
          - "availability"    = "A1" -> null
          - "confidentiality" = "C1" -> null
          - "integrity"       = "I1" -> null
          - "spoke_type"      = "APPI" -> null
          - "traceability"    = "T1" -> null
        }
        # (1 unchanged attribute hidden)
    }


  # databricks_secret_scope.kv_db will be created
  + resource "databricks_secret_scope" "kv_db" {
      + backend_type = (known after apply)
      + id           = (known after apply)
      + name         = "vk-secret-scope"

      + keyvault_metadata {
          + dns_name    = (known after apply)
          + resource_id = (known after apply)
        }
    }
```

```
│ Error: cannot create secret scope: Azure KeyVault is not available
│ 
│   with databricks_secret_scope.kv_db,
│   on tests.tf line 25, in resource "databricks_secret_scope" "kv_db":
│   25: resource "databricks_secret_scope" "kv_db" {
```

[image]

Update 4: (Partial workaround)

I found an ugly work around, it's to automate inside the terraform the usage of the Databricks's API 2.0

```
// Create SP in Databricks
resource "databricks_service_principal" "sp" {
  application_id = <SP_APPLICATION_ID> 
  external_id    = <SP_OBJECT_ID> 
  force          = false 
}
//Get the admin group in Databricks
data "databricks_group" "group_admins" { display_name = "admins" }
//Assign databricks users to Admin databricks group
resource "databricks_group_member" "admin_assign" {
  group_id  = data.databricks_group.group_admins.id
  member_id = databricks_service_principal.sp.id
  }
resource "null_resource" "databricks_secret_scope_api" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<-EOT atoken=$(curl -X POST \
     -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \ 
     https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TENANT_ID>/oauth2/v2.0/token \
     -d "client_id=<SP_APPLICATION_ID>" \
     -d "grant_type=client_credentials" \
     -d "scope=2ff814a6-3304-4ab8-85cb-cd0e6f879c1d%2F.default" \
     -d "client_secret=<SP_PASSWORD>" | jq --raw-output .access_token)
    curl -X POST \
      https://${<YOUR DATABRICKS BASE URL>}/api/2.0/secrets/scopes/create \
      --header "Content-type: application/json" \
      --header "Authorization: Bearer $atoken" \
      --data '{
        "scope": "<SCOPE NAME>",
        "scope_backend_type": "AZURE_KEYVAULT",
        "backend_azure_keyvault": {
          "resource_id": "<KEYVAUKT ID>",
          "dns_name": "<KEYVAULT URI>"
        }
      }'
  EOT
  }
  depends_on = [databricks_group_member.admin_assign]
}
```

This will run only ONCE. So if someone deletes the secret scope outsite the terraform, the state will never know it and thus never recreate it.

You can add a trigger to make it run all the time, it will destroy the terraform reference (NOT the secret scope) and create it back. It will fail because the secret scope already exists. You could improve this to run every time and list the secret scope names on databricks and create it only if you don't find it.

Answer (score 0):

> I tired to create  secret scope: Azure KeyVault & DataBricks using terraform I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

The issue you're encountering with Terraform when trying to create a Databricks secret scope backed by Azure KeyVault seems to be related to the permissions of the Service Principal (SP) you are using.

- Your Service Principal needs specific permissions to manage KeyVault secrets and Databricks. The error message suggests that the SP might not have the necessary permissions to access the KeyVault.
- Ensure the SP has 'Get', 'List', 'Set', and 'Delete' permissions on the KeyVault secrets. It also needs permissions to manage resources in Databricks.

The error message regarding the `azurerm_key_vault_access_policy` suggests a resource ID conflict. If a resource was created outside of Terraform and you now want to manage it with Terraform, you need to import it into your Terraform state.

**My terraform configuration:**

##### main.tf:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 2.0"
    }
    databricks = {
      source  = "databricks/databricks"
      version = "~> 0.3"  # Specify the version you need
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}

provider "databricks" {
  azure_workspace_resource_id = "/subscriptions/[your subscription_id]/resourceGroups/[resource_group_name]/providers/Microsoft.Databricks/workspaces/[databricks_name]"
}

data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "demorgvk1"
  location = "east us"
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "example" {
  name                        = "examplevk-vault"
  location                    = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name         = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  tenant_id                   = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  sku_name                    = "standard"

  # Other necessary configurations...
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "example" {
  key_vault_id       = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
  tenant_id          = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id          = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
  secret_permissions = ["Get", "List", "Set", "Delete"]
}

resource "databricks_secret_scope" "kv_db" {
  name = "vk-secret-scope"

  keyvault_metadata {
    resource_id = azurerm_key_vault.example.id
    dns_name    = azurerm_key_vault.example.vault_uri
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now open Databricks UI and create a notebook and run the command mentioned to list the available scopes created

This command lists available scopes on databricks:

```
dbutils.secrets.listScopes()
```

[image]

ref: https://docs.databricks.com/api/azure/workspace/secrets

ref:
[List databricks secret scope and find referred keyvault in azure databricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72725004/list-databricks-secret-scope-and-find-referred-keyvault-in-azure-databricks)

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/secret-scopes

Comment: The SP that used to deploy the KeyVault and Databricks has owner role. So it can create, delete, list, edit secret. And it works because I've created a cosmosDB and it adds the secret from cosmosdb to the keyvault through the SP. I've updated my post so you can verify roles of both user/SP

Comment: @BeGreen, the configuration you're looking for cannot be achieved with Owner permission alone on your SP. Along with that, we require Keyvault contributors, Key Vault Secrets Officers, and Contributor roles on the same  SP to achieve this. I tried to achieve the configuration with the same roles and I was able to provision the requirement.

Comment: I have added `Key Vault Contributor`, `Key Vault Secrets Officers`, and `Contributor` roles on the same SP, but it is still not working. I though it could be an issue with my provider. I was using the `host` option and switched to `azure_workspace_resource_id`, but nothing changed, both are resolved to find the provider.

Comment: @BeGreen can you please share the blocker info you have faced after trying the configuration I shared?

Comment: I've created it with an other Kv name since it's unique. And updated my post

Comment: @BeGreen Since you changed the name of KV to new one in the same configuration info the state file stored and the info you passed creates a conflict for terraform to pick the resource info ended up showing the error you faced. For this case use the same kv name which you used earlier try to import that using terraform import and run the script again. This is will work else if you really wanna create a new KV  destroy the existing infra configuration and retry with new KV from the beginning.

Comment: Still have the same error when I'm using the same ressource group/same KV and your `azurerm_role_assignment` + `databricks_secret_scope`. From what I can see, SP don't act like Users with roles. When I google this error code, people didn't find a solution. A github issue is still opened for this case. Starting to lose faith in the feasibility of this. We have contacts with Microsoft and Databricks, so I'll check with them and post the answser IF we find a solution.

Comment: @BeGreen From the solution provided, the configuration can be provisioned as you expected. you can see the secret scope which I shared in the image provided. try reprovisioning the code configuration from the beginning Issues might arise due to provider compatibility issues. Once try using with latest version provider with the necessary permissions mentioned.

Comment: I managed to use the Databricks API V2.0 to create a secret scope on my computer. But with the github Actions, the worker is using a proxy so it can not reach the databricks URL. So I was wondering if terraform could have this same issue with proxies?

Comment: I managed to use the Databricks API V2.0 to create a secret scope on my compute. But with the github Actions, the worker is using a proxy so it can not reach the databricks URL. So I was wondering if terraform could have this same issue with proxies?

Comment: @BeGreen  If your GitHub Actions worker is behind a proxy, Terraform might indeed face similar issues. Terraform respects standard proxy environment variables (HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY, NO_PROXY). Ensure these are correctly set in the environment where Terraform is running. If the proxy requires authentication, this needs to be included in the configuration as well.

Comment: The thing I did to "solve" my problem was to add a `null_resource` that would use databricks API 2.0 to create the secret scope. With the exact same Service Principal, keyvault databricks, same roles. So I really don't understand why the terraform made for this does not work for service principal. I've open a ticket in Azure Portal and also asked to our databricks support to check if they find a solution, i'll try to keep this up to date.

Answer (score 0):

@BeGreen, I solved this by adding a Provider to initialize the databricks workspace.

```
provider "databricks_provider" {
  #Get the workspace_url from the output of the databricks module
  alias               = "databricks"
  host                = workspace_url
  azure_client_id     = client_id 
  azure_client_secret = sp_clientSecret_value
  azure_tenant_id     = tenant_id
}

resource "databricks_secret_scope" "kv" {
  provider = databricks_provider.databricks
  name     = "secret-kv-managed"

  keyvault_metadata {
    resource_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.main.id
    dns_name    = data.azurerm_key_vault.main.vault_uri
  }
}
```